# how to delete from the last character at the end of a string, to a slash in the middle of a string?

Tags: ruby

assuming,

```
string1 = "/var/usr/local/noob/"
```

i need to start from the last character to the closest "/" preceiding it.

so i am expecting:

```
remove_last_block_of_string()
```

i should get

> "/var/usr/local/noob"

if i run remove_last_block_of_string() again,

```
"/var/usr/local"
```

running it again,

```
"/var/usr"
```

Comment: Not much of a difference between "/var/usr/local/noob/" and "/var/usr/local/noob"

Comment: You'll be happier if you use your language's facility for manipulating paths as paths, instead of as strings.  @Peter suggests some library called Pathname, which looks good to me (I'm not a ruby programmer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this:

```
sub(/\/[^\/]*$/, '')
```

as in,

```
>> "/var/usr/local/noob".sub(/\/[^\/]*$/, '')
=> "/var/usr/local"
>> _.sub(/\/[^\/]*$/, '')
=> "/var/usr"
```

but if you're manipulating file paths, it would be better to use the [Pathname](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/index.html) library.

Answer (score 2):

Or, `string1 = string1[0...string1.rindex('/')]`

---

```
>> def a s; s[0...s.rindex('/')]; end
>> t = "/var/usr/local/noob/"
=> "/var/usr/local/noob/"
>> t = a t
=> "/var/usr/local/noob"
>> t = a t
=> "/var/usr/local"
```

We could have even more fun:

```
>> class MyPath < String
>>   def root; self[0...self.rindex('/')]; end
>> end
=> nil
>> t = MyPath.new("/var/usr/local/noob/")
=> "/var/usr/local/noob/"
>> t = t.root
=> "/var/usr/local/noob"
>> t = t.root
=> "/var/usr/local"
>> t = t.root
=> "/var/usr"
```

Or, you could just monkeypatch String itself...

```
>> class String
>>   def root; self[0...self.rindex('/')]; end
>> end
=> nil
>> t = "/var/usr/local/noob/"
=> "/var/usr/local/noob/"
>> t = t.root
=> "/var/usr/local/noob"
>> t = t.root
=> "/var/usr/local"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle the general case, then use a regex as provided by other answers.

However the Ruby `File` class handles the specific case where you are dealing with file paths:

```
File.dirname("/var/usr/local/noob/")
# outputs "/var/usr/local"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:
    string1 = (string1.match /(.*)//)[1] if string1.include? "/"

Answer (score 0):

You could use split and join methods from String and Array objects:

```
>> s = "/var/usr/local/noob/"
=> "/var/usr/local/noob/"
>> p = s.split('/')
=> ["", "var", "usr", "local", "noob"]
>> p.slice!(-1)
=> "noob"
>> p.join('/')
=> "/var/usr/local"
>> p.slice!(-1)
=> "local"
>> p.join('/')
=> "/var/usr"
>> p.slice!(-1)
=> "usr"
>> p.join('/')
=> "/var"
```

Now you just have to put these two functions in an object that holds the state of the string whose last block is being removed.

I don't know much of ruby but something like the following could be implemented:

```
 // Pseusdo - Java
 class LastBlockRemoved {
      private String string;
      private Array currentState;

      public String remove_last_block_of_string() {
          currentState = string.split("/");
          string = currentState.join("/");
          return string
      }

 }
```

Or however that is coded in Ruby :P

BTW It would be great if someone could actually implement that class, so I can learn how it is done ;)